# Detect current foreground Activity and reload it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, reload, activity-finish

My Problem:
In MainActivity I start to download some data from the Internet via XML Parser. This data is displayed on every Screen of my App. It is like a Database.

While downloading and saving data, the user of the App can navigate through the hole app. If downloading and saving data is finished, **I want to detect and reload the current foreground Activity**. I need to do this, to display the new data.

I can detect the current Activity with the ActivityManager and can start it with the ComponentName with the method "startActivity(Intent.makeMainActivity(componentName)". But then the old activity is also there when I navigate back with the ActionBar-BackButton.
I do this in the AsyncTasks onPostExecute-Method after downloading Data.

Any Ideas how to do it?

```
protected void onPostExecute(MainActivity.UrlParams result) {
    Toast.makeText(result.contextMain, "Daten wurden erfolgreich aktualisiert!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Aktualisiert aktive Activity damit die neuen Daten angezeigt werden!
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) result.contextMain.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    componentInfo.getPackageName();
    Intent intent = Intent.makeMainActivity(componentInfo);
    result.contextMain.startActivity(intent);

    //myApp.getCurrentActivity().set
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download your data is service, not in AsyncTask
2. Register some `BroadcastReceiver` in your `MainActivity` in `onStart()`, and unregister it in `onStop()`. Refresh your view in this receiver
3. When data are downloaded, make a broadcast to call activity, that data are ready.
   Disadvantage of this method is that you should save your data somewhere. You can of course pass data in the intent, but only if data are small

Comment: There is a library called ```EventBus``` that does this for you and it's awesome. If you don't want to use the library, what Tomasz suggested is the best approach.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a simplier way to do this?

Comment: As danypata mentioned, you can use `EventBus` library. I think this is the simplest, nice method, without any hacking and obscuring code

Comment: I read a little bit of "getting Started" and "modes", I think the ASYNK Mode is the right one for me. 
I hope it is as easy to use as it looks

Comment: @danypata
I created the MessageEvent class
In onPostExecute I post the eventMessage "reload"
and in the Activity I registered and unregistered in onStart / onStop

but the Method onEventAsync is not called...what I have to do?

Comment: ITS DONE, i missunderstood the @Subscriber ThreadMode -> I need MAIN.
---Know it recreates the Activity and the new data is shown and the Activitystack is not manipulated
---THANK YOU